# PayPal Recurring Payments and Item Numbers

Tags: paypal, recurring-billing

I am having my users select a product for purchase, which is a monthly subscription.  It is renewed every 30 days.  My intention was to create a Recurring Payment and handle the subscription renewal via an IPN.  However, I am unable to set a product number and get it to return in the IPN.  I have several subscription products to configure and if I am unable to distinguish between them in the IPN's, I can't perform the actions on my side to renew their subscription for another 30 days.

First, am I doing this the right way?  Is this the proper usage of recurring payments?  If so, how can I set the identifying information I need?  Is it set when the billing agreement is created?  Which parameters do I use to set this?  I've been unable to find a comprehensive list.

Comment: You should be able to include itemized details with CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile no problem.  Can you provide a sample of a request you're sending to create the profile?

Comment: Andrew, thanks for the help.  Looking up CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile I was able to find the parameters I was looking for.  Part of my problem was implementing PayPal in a way I wasn't familiar with via a library I had just started to learn, Payum.

If you can structure your comment as an answer I'd happily accept it.  Thanks again.